# How do I write to a plist with defaults?

Tags: terminal, catalina, plist, defaults

I've been googling around, reading documentation, but for the love of me cannot really figure out how to write to plist files on Catalina using `defaults`.

I can easily do these changes:  `defaults write com.apple.dock mcx-expose-disabled -bool TRUE`

And I can see them reflected when running `defaults read com.apple.dock`:

```
    "expose-group-apps" = 1;
    largesize = 58;
    "last-messagetrace-stamp" = "674243800.104244";
    launchanim = 0;
    loc = "en_GB:AT";
    magnification = 1;
    "mcx-expose-disabled" = 1;  <---
    mineffect = scale;
    "mod-count" = 151;
```

Now, the big problem comes when I want to write this parameter ("file-label" = Safari):

```
    "expose-group-apps" = 1;
    largesize = 58;
    "last-messagetrace-stamp" = "674243800.104244";
    launchanim = 0;
    loc = "en_GB:AT";
    magnification = 1;
    "mcx-expose-disabled" = 1;
    mineffect = scale;
    "mod-count" = 151;
    "persistent-apps" =     (
                {
            GUID = 2155926347;
            "tile-data" =             {
                book = {length = 556, bytes = 0x626f6f6b 2c020000 00000410 30000000 ... 04000000 00000000 };
                "bundle-identifier" = "com.apple.Safari";
                "dock-extra" = 0;
                "file-data" =                 {
                    "_CFURLString" = "file:///Applications/Safari.app/";
                    "_CFURLStringType" = 15;
                };
                "file-label" = Safari;                    <---- This one right here
                "file-mod-date" = 190017379983659;
                "file-type" = 41;
```

How does one follow the trail on the plist file for `defaults` to accept it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I think you'd have to use `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` instead of `defaults` for this -- see my answer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355850/in-bash-how-do-i-use-defaults-write-on-a-plist-for-a-existing-element-in-an-arr).

Comment: Or even BBEdit. The defaults command doesn't really handle complex nested data structures.

Comment: Thank you @GordonDavisson! I will definitely look into it tonight. It does seem the path to follow.

Thank you also @benwiggy! I will check BBEdit out!